# Does a NSURLConnection break when a phone call arrives?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

What happens to a URLconnection when a URLconnection for a particular application is performing and a phone call arrives at the same time?

Comment: You pick up the phone and talk. What else?

Comment: I'm asking about the urlconnection. Does it continues or it will break at that moment?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it continues - but why not try it?

Comment: Check this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-tasks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends on your app and the connect, first your app must support background running. Then if the internet connection is GRPS, CDMA or EDGE your connection is dropped and `NSURLConnection` will receive an error if the connection is not reestablished with the time out period.
On 3G and WiFi you can have data and voice at the same time. On LTE all data connection are dropped and the witches back to UMTS(3G) see comment by [Codo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413337/codo)

Comment: That means I've to implement the code for background task on application delegate methods?

Comment: Yes, since you app could be backgrounded.

Comment: Just a side note: The way LTE is currently used by the phone companies, it does not support voice. So if you receive a phone call, the phone drops all data connections and reverts UMTS. The plan is to have voice over LTE one day.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question as iOS supports background task for only ten minutes so after 10 minutes the connection will lost? Or I've to set something in the plist file to extend the time like "VOIP"?